# In java pattern matcher(regex) how to iterate and replace each text with different text

Tags: java, regex

I want to check for pattern matching, and if the pattern matches, then I wanted to replace those text matches with the element in the test array at the given index.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] test={"one","two","three","four"}
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\d)+");
        String text="{\"test1\":\"$1\",\"test2\":\"$5\",\"test3\":\"$3\",\"test4\":\"$4\"}";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    

while(matcher.find()) {
       System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());
       System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("test"));
    }
  System.out.println(text);
}

}
```

I want the end result text string to be in this format:

```
{\"test1\":\"one\",\"test2\":\"$two\",\"test3\":\"three\",\"test4\":\"four\"}
```

but the while loop is exiting after one match and `"test"` is replaced everywhere like this:

```
{"test1":"test","test2":"test","test3":"test","test4":"test"}
```

Using the below code I got the result:

```
  public class test {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] test={"one","two","three","four"};
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\d)+");
            String text="{\"test1\":\"$1\",\"test2\":\"$2\",\"test3\":\"$3\",\"test4\":\"$4\"}";
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, test[Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)) - 1]);
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    
    }
    }
```

But, if I have a replacement text array like this,

```
String[] test={"$$one","two","three","four"};
```

then, because of the `$$`, I am getting an exception in thread "main":

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
> at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:857)**

Comment: pretty sure that you mean that you want the end result of `{\"test1\":\"one\",\"test2\":\"two\",\"test3\":\"three\",\"test4\":\"four\"}`. That is, I don't think you want the `"$"`, right? It's hard to tell from the post because you have both "$two" and "one" in your examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following line is your problem:

```java
System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("test"));
```

If you remove it the loop will walk through all matches.

As a solution for your problem, you could replace the loop with something like this:

For Java 8:

```java
StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    String r = test[Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) - 1];
    matcher.appendReplacement(out, r);
}
matcher.appendTail(out);
System.out.println(out.toString());
```

For Java 9 and above:

```java
String x = matcher.replaceAll(match -> test[Integer.parseInt(match.group(1)) - 1]);
System.out.println(x);
```

This only works, if you replace the `$5` with `$2` which is what I would assume is your goal.

Concerning the `$` signs in the replacement string, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) states:

> A dollar sign ($) may be included as a literal in the replacement string by preceding it with a backslash (\$).

In other words, you must write your replacement array as `String[] test = { "\\$\\$one", "two", "three", "four" };`

Comment: But for each match, I wanted to replace from string array like $1---->one,  $2--->two ....

Comment: But i am getting below error The method replaceAll(String) in the type Matcher is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> match) -> {})

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to mention that this method is only available in Java 9 and above. You probably run Java 8?

Comment: I got the solution I have updated in question itself, But if I have replacementtext array like this String[] test={"$$one","two","three","four"}; then becuase of $$ I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference

Comment: I've just updated my solution with a version for Java 8.

Comment: Thank You!! same thing I also did but can you able to tell how I can overcome the above mentioned problem, I have updated in question also.

Comment: Oh, you have added the same solution to your question :D. For me this works as expected

Comment: Suppose replacement array is like this String[] test={"$$one","two","three","four"}; then becuase of $$ in 0 index if I ma trying to replace I am getting error

Comment: You should probably include the new replacement array in your updated question. Running the posted code works just fine :P

Comment: public class test {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] test={"$$one","two","three","four"};
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\d)+");
        String text="{\"test1\":\"$1\",\"test2\":\"$2\",\"test3\":\"$3\",\"test4\":\"$4\"}";
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, test[Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)) - 1]);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());

}
}

Comment: I've updated the answer again. You must replace the dollar signs in the replacement array with \$, such that they are not interpreted by the matcher.

Comment: How can I check for $ using regex and replace using ternary operator if exists.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand correctly, but if `r` is the string you want to use as replacement you could do something like `r.contains("$") ? r.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$") : r` to escape all dollar signs.

Answer (score 0):

I can do a regex solution if you like, but this is much easier (assuming this is the desired output).

```java
      int count = 1;
      for (String s : test) {
         text = text.replace("$" + count++, s);
      }
      System.out.println(text);
```

It prints.

`{"test1":"one","test2":"two","test3":"three","test4":"four"}`

Comment: Thank you!! but I wanted regex solution because the count variable you are incrementing may not be continuous.